# LocalStorage with an object array

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When storing an array in local storage, then retrieving the results like this works fine

```
myarray = ["cat", "dog", 1];
localStorage["storedArray"] = JSON.stringify(myarray);
JSON.parse(localStorage["storedArray"]);
```

But when i try to store an object array full of Google maps LatLng information all that is printed is [object][object], [object][object] and so on.

```
localStorage["positions"] = JSON.stringify(this.positions);
JSON.parse(localStorage["positions"]);
```

Same code just changing the array stored, I know the information in it is fine since Im using it to print lines on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
localStorage["positions"] = JSON.stringify(this.positions[0]);
JSON.parse(localStorage["positions"]);
```

You could try using a console.log to display the [object]. If it has indexes you will need to reference the index as I mentioned in the above example. Open your browser console and see what is the output, and change your code accordingly.

```
console.log(this.positions);
```

Hope this helps in some way. Hope you find the answer and share it.